# How can I verify the authenticity of requests from an app to my web service

Tags: validation, client-server, httprequest

I would like to make application for mobile/iPhone/iPad.
In app I would like to make an HTTP request to a web service.
How can I ensure that this request comes from my app or desktop browser or mobile browser.

The user can change the "user agent" string in the HTTP request header.

So please any one tell me how can we do that?

Comment: A question should never be down-voted without  at least one comment as to why it deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be 100% certain, you can just take certain steps to be almost certain.

- Start by using SSL between the app and the server, that way no one can intercept traffic.
- Then create an API token that is hardcoded in the app itself, and is supplied to the API with every request. The API then rejects any request with an invalid API token.
- Using a custom user-agent can help, again rejecting any request that doesn't match the user agent.

There are countless things you can do to make it HARDER for people to make API requests, but it's almost impossible to guarantee the request is from the app itself. Just make sure that all API endpoints are properly secured with some kind of 'user' authentication and you should be alright.

I'd definitely recommend using SSL whatever you do though, as if you use things like API keys without SSL, then someone could intercept the request and obtain the API key rendering it useless.

Comment: Thanks PaReeOhNos for this useful information. i think ssl will work for me. and one more thing In most of the app there only one time login then its always login when we open the app. how this possible.is this same as token login which is send by the server at the time login.

Comment: Yeah same thing. So when the user logs in, the server will issue a token which the app will remember. All requests then supply that token. If it isn't supplied, the server rejects the request

Comment: `Then create an API token that is hardcoded in the app itself, and is supplied to the API with every request. The API then rejects any request with an invalid API token.`


How should we store this api token in app?